# learning swift: expressions are not allowed at the top level

Tags: swift

I'm learning Swift. I met a problem cannot be solved.

```
import UIKit

func helloword(str:String) {
    print(str)
}

helloword("say")
```

I use `helloword("say")` but Xcode tell me the error:

> expressions are not allowed at the top level

Comment: this is in playground? am i right? in playground & view controller there is no error or warning. which version of xcode & swift you have?

Comment: I can say that he wasn't in playground~

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply call this method anywhere in the file. It must be called in a control flow. I mean call it inside a function.

For example, call your function from your viewDidLoad method like so :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
self.helloword("say")  // here self is the View Controller itself
}
```

Comment: use func in the class？

Comment: no need to call function using self only if function called from async/sync task

Comment: @AkshanshThakur  I define a func out of class outside of the class,You may not understand it.   I try use helloword in a control flow,succeesd.thinks.

Comment: @jianxing798 I thought of that, but it is very unusual. In general you would wanna create a new class and code there add method there, then you can create an instance of that class and access the method.